# Text shortening method in jquery not shortening div text

Tags: jquery, text

I am pulling some text from a database, and I would like the div it appears in to shorten it to a certain character amount.  I am using this:

Script:

```
$(".activity_body").text($(this).text().substr(0, 120)+'...');
```

HTML:

```
<div class="activity_body">{{$fanartist->description}} <a href="/artists/{{$fanartist->id}}">See more...</a></div>
```

This isn't shortening the text like it should.  Do you know what may be going wrong here?  Thank you.

This div class appears many times (dynamic rendering), does this have anything to do with it?  Thank you.

Comment: If you are pulling the text from DB then its better to strip it from server itself.

Comment: Which server side language you use?

Comment: php, I am using Laravel 4 for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using php then you can shorten the string from server itself using php  `substr` function like:

> `substr ( $string , $start ,$length )`

which returns the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters.

See the function in [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 1):

Your `this` is not referring to `$(".activity_body")`. You need do one or the other of the following:

```
var activityBody = $(".activity_body");
activityBody.text(activityBody.text().substr(0, 120)+'...');
// or
$(".activity_body").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 120)+'...');
});
```

Here's a fiddle where it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/FSxj5/

Comment: hmm, the first solution isn't working.  Let me check the second.

Comment: yea hmmm, the second one isn't working either :(  Any idea what may be going on?

Comment: No idea since I just opened the chrome dev tools on this page and ran `$('.prettyprint').each(function() { $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,120)+'...'); });` and it shortened all the code blocks.

Comment: Just added a fiddle where it is working. What are you getting in the console?